# when loading a huge file into hadoop cluster , what happends if the client failed while transfering data to datanodes?

Tags: hadoop

for example,the file is 1280MB and the hdfs block is 128MB，what happends when the
client only transfered 3 blocks and then failed? does the NameNode obtain a file of 3 blocks or delete the 3 blocks ？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not delete the 3 blocks. So here is how it works, we assume block 4 is in the next of the queue maintained by the FSDataOuputStream. After it writes some x bytes due to some network issue the datanode fails, the pipeline is first closed and any data written to that is deleted, the new good datanode is given a new identity and is added to the queue and the same is communicated to name node to update the metadata information for block 4 and then the data would be written to that newly identified datanode starting from the 1st byte of that block. Anatomy of file write in The Definitive Guide would help you in a better understanding on how it is done.

Comment: what if it was the client failed instead of the datanode, this means it will stop transfering this file by the client side,and is namenode will also reserve this incomplete file?

Comment: It will not retain the metadata,because finally once the file is successfully written to HDFS Distributedfilesystem sends a submit call back to namenode(once all the checksums are verified) to commit the metadata info, else it ignores it.

Comment: thank you verymuch,is there any more detailed materials you can recommend for me?

Comment: You could refer http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/02/understanding-hdfs-recovery-processes-part-1/  which describes in detail about the HDFS recovery process. Please accept the answer if it resolves your problem.